# Workshop submission by a first year student, does it count?

Tags: phd, workshop

I have asked earlier this question in that post [Submitting Workshop Proposal by A first Year PhD student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/132941/103209)

I asked my supervisor and he is okay, but I was astonished that he told me that I have to take permission from the head of the department, in general, he didn't give me a bit of useful advice.

To have a paper it requires time since I am working with collaborative groups, I cannot publish yet and I want to be engaged more in scientific activities.

My question now: Does it count to a first-year Ph.D. student to submit a workshop proposal ( I am going to have other professors, however, I will be in charge of all the logistics)

I don't know whether it could be wise to invest time in submitting a workshop proposal.

Comment: Does it count **for what?**  — _I was astonished that he told me that I have to take permission from the head of the department_ — I am also astonished by this.

Comment: Does it count as having a paper ( having a paper would take time, but I have a draft).  Yes, indeed I dont know what to say, but my advisor doesnot have a discretion to do something and that would also freak me out.

Comment: I seeked help from psychologist and phd counseller, but none of them were helpful! I   am very confused and I dont know whether I am the problem, I dont know, I cannot see myself having a potential to continue in academia although I had an academic job in homecountry and have to return with a degree.

Comment: to be a lecturer, but I never liked my home university and I dont want to be a professor, I love research, and maybe do something new, but the current situation shows that I am nothing literally compared to my colleagues.

Comment: @JeffE, possibly the use of departmental facilities and resources by a conference needs at least nominal approval from the department head. Could be entirely routine. To reserve rooms, get some coffee, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it count as having a paper

That depends on the workshop.  Your submission counts as a (peer-reviewed, published) paper if and only if

1. The submission is an actual manuscript, and not just a short (few-paragraph) abstract, AND
2. Your submission is accepted by the committee after significant review by your peers (the workshop committee)
3. After some revision, the manuscript will be made available to the public in some persistent form, either paper or electronic, that can be found many years in the future by someone who did not attend the workshop.

Many workshops fail all three of these conditions—submissions consist of only few-paragraph abstracts, which are lightly reviewed by the committee (to eliminate obvious garbage), and which are printed verbatim onto paper handouts that are distributed at the conference, but never made public elsewhere.

This may be a language issue, but a "workshop proposal" doesn't sound like a paper describing your own research, but rather a **proposal** for a **workshop** that you want to *organize*, either for other people to present *their* research, or to collaborate on new research, or both.  Organizing a workshop could be valuable experience and a positive point on your CV, but it does not count as a "paper".

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I will try to ask our project collaborators and see what they think! I am also trying to finish a good results and then a paper would come.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you asked your advisor for *permission* which was granted.

You should also (or instead) ask for *advice*. Not "can I do this?" but "do you think this will help me, or should I be focusing on _____ instead?"

Your advisor is the person best positioned to determine whether this is a useful move for you. My outside opinion is that it is not and that at your stage of career you should be focused on building your own research: you want to be known for your research, not for your workshop organization skills. However, *I am not your advisor and am not close enough to you to give this advice*.

Comment: Literally, I have asked him whether this could be useful for me as a PhD student.

Comment: BTW, before that I was working on this topic for more than two years, I have good network with researchers in the field! I have also give a talk and one of well-established professor expressed his interest to join in workshop submission.

Comment: @Monika When you asked whether it would be useful, what did he say? Take his advice.

Comment: He said it might be good for me and the project as well! and he told me that I have to engaged bigger names and inform them I will be in charge of logistics. My concern is wasting time on something will not add to me.

Comment: @Monika Say that to him. "I know you said this might be good, but I'm worried my time on this will not really benefit me and should be spent on other things instead; what do you think?" Then take his advice.

Comment: I forgot to say, I have already had an honest talk with him, he said go for it and organize, but as I told before he isnot in charge of this research line.

Comment: @Monika I'll say it a fourth time: take his advice. That's what an advisor is for. If these answers are so specific to your research line that it doesn't relate to his at all then either you need to go to a different lab where you can be advised properly or you need to change your research focus. StackExchange will not substitute for having an advisor.

Comment: This is answer I am looking for !\Exactly! I think I am in the wrong direction!